# plotting image with axes in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision

**Am trying to plot an image with axes just like in matplotlib with OpenCV.**
[image]

**The above image is plotted with matplotlib** 
[image]

**The above image is plotted with OpenCV** 

Can anybody tell me how to plot the image with axes in opencv?!

Comment: OpenCV doesn't provide such a method AFAIK. Just use the `matplotlib` method with your OpenCV colour channels reversed, i.e. pass `OpenCVImage[:,:,::-1]` to `matplotlib`.